# HTAccess subdomain using wildcard to point to single folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a website which has many registered user. I want to provide each user with a personal url using htaccess.

I have setup a wild card subdomain, what I need to do is:

myname.mydomain.com -> should show contents form /somefolder which is in my root domain and it should not change the url.
In that folder i will parse the current url ie. myname. and show contents for myname.

I have tried following things but they are not helping.

Try 1:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !<weburl>$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain[dot]com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://<weburl>/somefolder/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Try 2:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !<weburl>$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain[dot]com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://<weburl>/somefolder/ [L]
```

Try 3:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !<weburl>$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain[dot]com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://<weburl>/somefolder/ [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^somefolder/ /somefolder/ [L,NC]
```